# Convert Utf-8 String To Windows Cp-1258

Tags: c#

I want to convert a text file from `utf-8` to `windows cp-1258` by C# console, here is my code but it does not work, the output file content is not `cp-1258`

```
string path = @"E:\mp4\test\Cyborg.txt";
string readText = File.ReadAllText(path);
Encoding vnmese = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1258");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(readText);
byte[] vnBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, vnmese, utfBytes);
string msg = vnmese.GetString(vnBytes);
string path2 = @"E:\mp4\test\MyTest.txt";
File.WriteAllText(path2, msg, vnmese);
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: The line : string readText = File.ReadAllText(path); corrupts the data because it defaults to ASCII encoding which removes non printable characters.

Comment: @jdweng: No it doesn't - `File.ReadAllText` uses UTF-8 by default.

Comment: Jon : yes that is what Microsoft says on their website but it is not always true.

Comment: @jdweng: Do you have *any* evidence of that? It's always been absolutely fine for me - if you're going to assert that a very, very widely used method doesn't behave as documented, you should really have concrete evidence to back it up.

Comment: @jdweng: Here's my evidence that it *does* use UTF-8: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/file.cs,786 and in github for .NET Core: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs#L351

Comment: @jdweng : thanks but i tried added string readText = File.ReadAllText(path ,Encoding.UTF8); but it still not work

Comment: Rule #1: it is never a bug in the framework.  Rule #2: every hard to diagnose bug starts with a wrong assumption.  You have to at a minimum document how you concluded that the file does not contain 1258 encoded text.  A hex dump with a red circle is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is going through all kinds of steps it doesn't need to. All you need is:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("input.txt");
Encoding encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1258);
File.WriteAllText("output.txt", text, encoding);
```

That's far easier to understand, and should work fine.

However, as far as I can see, your code *should* already work - which suggests one of three options:

- Your original text file *isn't* in UTF-8
- Your expectations of a file in Windows-1258 are invalid
- Your file contains text that can't be represented in Windows-1258

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
            string path = @"E:\mp4\test\Cyborg.txt";
            Encoding vnmese = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1258");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, vnmese);
            string path2 = @"E:\mp4\test\MyTest.txt";
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path2, true, vnmese);
            writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering but it does not work, there is an error writer.Write(reader); has null exception

Comment: I forgot to add the ReadToEnd

Comment: thnaks but it still not work,i open E:\mp4\test\MyTest.txt but it is empty

Comment: Does Cyborg.txt have data?  If you are not getting any data then the encoding is removing the data so you do not have 1258 encoding.  Try using Encoding.UTF8 instead which will not change any of the data.  You do not need to use GetEncoding.  Just replace vnmese with Encoding.UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 Encoding vnmese = Encoding.GetEncoding("1258");
```

or

```
 Encoding vnmese = Encoding.GetEncoding("1252");
```

Just remove

> Windows-

Comment: Thank you for the help but it does not work ,it thrown: "'1258' is not a supported encoding name.

Comment: have u try 1252?

Comment: try to use 'System.Text.EncodingProvider ppp;
ppp = System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance;
Encoding.RegisterProvider(ppp);'

Comment: but i want to convert to 1258, not 1252, and 1252 not work, too